# Suppress a Flutter package UI to make use of my own UI

Tags: android, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Basically, I want to use the Flutter mobile packages https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_mobile_vision#-readme-tab- without utilizing there UI interface provided. I mean a simple example pops up a UI associated with the package, I would like to suppress this so I can build my own UI on top of it.

Comment: Probably better to raise the question in https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_mobile_vision/issues/new

Comment: You can always extend the package and provide your own layout. You can also checkout the [Texture](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html) widget to display the camera without leaving your Flutter app.

Comment: Also consider [Firebase ML Vision](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_ml_vision) Morrison Chang gave a great demo last night at NYC Flutter Meetup

Comment: @RichardHeap I have already implemented a solution using the Firebase ML vision but suffering different fate with that. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22555#issuecomment-426552955  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625261/running-the-firebase-ml-vision-api-calls-inside-a-compute-isolate-function for more details. This is the reason I have decided to try this Flutter Mobile Vision package since I saw the example was very fluent with the UI.

Comment: @KirollosMorkos Can you provide a brief example please?

Comment: @Federico You can look at the [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera) for the Camera plugin for an example. [Here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/lib/camera.dart#L100) is where the `Texture` is used in the Dart code and [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java#L263) is where the `SurfaceTexture` is defined in the Android code.